# Prevent fish command from executing through fish_preexec

Tags: shell, command, fish

I want to pre-process all commands being sent to fish. I'm aware that this can be done through `fish_preexec`, since it passes the literal command as an argument. However, I also want to prevent the command from being executed altogether given certain conditions. I don't want to quit the fish shell; I want to keep the current shell alive, and just print a `"command not executed"` message.

Does fish support anything like this?

Answer (score 4):

This is tricky, but you can do it by rebinding the enter key to a custom function, like this:

```
function execute_ifnotls
    if test (commandline) = 'ls'
        echo
        echo "No"
        commandline ""
        commandline -f repaint
    else
        commandline -f execute
    end
end
bind \r execute_ifnotls
bind \n execute_ifnotls
```

produces:

```
> ls
No
> whoami
david
```

Comment: This definitely looks like a good idea. I'll have to do some testing to see if this prevents multi-line commands, but this looks like the best bet atm. I'll accept the answer if I can get it to work with multi-line.

Comment: It doesn't prevent multiline editing, although you do get some visual glitches.

Comment: @Zanchey I can't get multiline editing working for me? every time I type enter this function executes...